# bash: make cgi-script don't open new page

Tags: html, bash, cgi

Is there a way to stay on existing page when initialize a cgi-script?
Script is written using bash. The page itself is very big to just echo his contens.

Comment: This is not controlled by the target page.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you wan to run a server-side CGI script from a wbe page without reloading the page? You can do this using AJAX - you would write some JavaScript to call the server-side script, this wouldn't require a new page to be loaded in the browser.

Something [like this](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first) should do it